# GetEntryURL in the Destination of a link

Tags: asp.net, outsystems

I trying to set the Destination of the link in the email. But Iam not sure how to set the identifier as the input parameter.Below are the list of input parameters of the page.
[image]

So I am trying to pass the parameters using GetEntryURL as

```
"http://" + Site.PageDirect + GetEntryURL("RiderRouteEditCreate","iCommute","WantsWithdraw",False,"ViewRouteEdit",False,"RouteId",NullIdentifier(),"ViewRiderEdit",False,"IsAdmin",False,"RiderId")
```

I am not sure how to set the RiderId as it is the Dynamic here. Can anyone please suggest me how can I approach this.

Comment: There are several things I don't understand from your question. What is this GetEntityURL action that you speak of? And what type does the RiderId has (in both, the page input and GetEntryURL action)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your Email have an input parameter name it RiderId.

Do not forget to change the data type of RiderId to be the identifier you want.

Your Email will look like this:

[image: Sample Image]

Then your link can be something like this:

```
"http://" + Site.PageDirect + GetEntryURL("RiderRouteEditCreate","iCommute","WantsWithdraw",False,"ViewRouteEdit",False,"RouteId",NullIdentifier(),"ViewRiderEdit",False,"IsAdmin",False,"RiderId", RiderId)
```